# how to access variable from another .js using .js?

Tags: javascript

I want to use within a js file a variable that belongs to another js file.
ie I want to run file1.js using a file2.js variable.

Does anyone know how to do this?
is it possible to access a variable from another .js file?

file1.js:

```
oScript = document.createElement('script');
oScript.src = 'file2.js';
oScript.type = 'text/javascript';
document.body.appendChild(oScript);
console.log(message);
```

file2.js:

```
var message = [{"id":"01", "name":"Text A", "text":"more text"},{"id":"02", "name":"Text B", "text":"more text"}];
```

Comment: are you calling these files with a script tag?

Comment: This code should work fine. `message` looks like a global variable, so it should be readable after your insert the script tag. What issue are you having?

Comment: You could create global variable that can be accessed by `window.variableName`

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure `console.log(message)` isn't run until after file2 is loaded. I suggest using AJAX instead of trying to inject the file into your HTML.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'file2.js');
xhr.onload = function() {
    eval(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(message);
    window.message = message; //Include this if you need message to be a global variable
};
xhr.send();
```

However, I highly recommend using a JSON file to store the value of the message variable and loading that with ajax, rather than using JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just a `script` tag if you use the `load` event:

```
oScript = document.createElement('script');
oScript.src = 'file2.js';
oScript.type = 'text/javascript';
oScript.onload = function() {
    console.log(message);
};
document.body.appendChild(oScript);
```

Or:

```
oScript = document.createElement('script');
oScript.src = 'file2.js';
oScript.type = 'text/javascript';
oScript.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log(message);
});
document.body.appendChild(oScript);
```

Comment: oh! thank you so much. I was able to use your example and make my script work. Thank you very much for your explanation.